# How to get JSON data from google plus api

Tags: java, json, google-plus

I was trying to get the google plus public data of particular profile. I have succeed in getting the JSON chunk to some extent using JAVA code i.e., the following image

[Here I am getting basic few details like person_name,id,profile_image etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXh4o.png)

I have tried by using the below api to get public information . BUt not succeeded 100 %

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/userId/circles
```

What is the way to get the public data including posts of a person and members public data in our circles through JAVA code?
Can anyone suggest me how to acheive it ?

Comment: Are you using [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/plus/v1#samples) to fetch the data?

Comment: yes. Here is the API which i am using  " https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people?query=username&key= ur key "                                                                   @Sangram